# Reading csv with pandas - dealing with imbalanced rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have more than 1 million rows, and there is a very long text field making some of my rows imbalanced. This causes some rows to have more columns than my header. I fixed this with following:

```
read_csv('filename.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

The problem here is it appears there are some rows witch less columns then my header. This is a problem (some fields shift.)

How can I fix this? Is there a way that (I blame that long text field) to act as a one field?

---

edit after comment

Field delimiter is comma.
When I run `df.dtypes` all fields but one seems to be object, however I originally have int, and datetime fields, read as objects by pandas.

---

edit after comment 2

here is header for what I have in .csv
id(int),textField(string),id2(char),score(int),type(string),length(int),name(string),datetime(datetime),size(int),email(string)

The main problem is textField area. the others cannot have and foul characers for escaping csv syntax. However textField is created by users, it can be anything in unicode; emojis, non english chars funny quote etc.

Comment: are your fields delimited and if so what is the format?

Comment: refer updated question

Comment: Please show a small sample of your data illustrating the problem.

Comment: question updated @BrenBarn

Comment: @BediE: Not a description of the data, an actual *sample* of data that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @BrenBarn I wish I could, but I can not present the data.

Comment: Ok, tell us if your text fields are enclosed by quotes, or any other character. If not, it'll be difficult to parse your file.

Answer (score 1):

> The main problem is `textField` area. the others cannot have and foul
>   characers for escaping csv syntax. However textField is created by
>   users, it can be anything in unicode; emojis, non english chars funny
>   quote etc.

The `textField` should be surrounded with double quotes, and any quote inside that field has to be escaped with another quote.

Since that field can contain any character, chances are that some of those fields are multiline, which would also explain why some rows have less columns while the other data seems to be valid.

So make sure your parser supports, and is set to use multiline. But this will only work if those fields are properly quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I investigated some samples, this is exactly the case. I was able to export my dataset in json, so I have solved my problem, but the question remains.

Comment: @BediE - Do you mean you were creating the csv file yourself? In this case, quoting the fields (or at least `textField`) and escaping the quotes inside should solve the problem, as long as the parser can handle multiline fields.

Comment: No! I did not create .csv myself. I export it from a DB where this field is a multi-lingual text fields. I checked it, I don't know where it's handled but I see cases where some fields are wrapped around with double quotes, and I'm pretty sure that some rows contain "s that cause imbalanced quotation.